# The default Date format is being displayed after i change my @Html.EditorFor to @Html.TextBox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.textbox

I have defined the date format on my model class as follow:-

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:f}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Date Taken")]
        public DateTime DateTaken { get; set; }
```

and it was displayed properly on the `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTaken)`, but after i changed the `editorfor` to be `@Html.TextBox("DateTaken", null, new { @id = "DateTaken"+item.ToString() })` ; The date format is now being displayed as *03/05/2012* instead of *05 May 2012*,, so how can i apply the intended date format on the `@Html.TextBox`

BR

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Html.TextBox` instead of `Html.TextBoxFor`?

Answer (score 0):

Without getting too fancy you could just do this:

```
@Html.TextBox("DateTaken", Model.DateTaken.ToString("d MMM yyyy"), 
                           new { @id = ... })
```